# Why is my enum.Parse method failing?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to dynamically set an enum based on the value in a string so far so good I don't know what I've been doing wrong. I have the following code:

```
public enum TagLabels : long
    {
        TurnLeft = 0x0000000000000000000030A38DB1,
        TurnRight = 0x00000000000000000000307346CC,
        LiftApproach = 0x0000000000000000000012107A8D
    }
```

TagLabels IDs;

```
string someID = "0x0000000000000000000012107A8D"; 
IDs = (TagLabels)Enum.Parse(typeof(TagLabels), someID ); //<== I get runtime error on this line
```

I cannot see what's wrong with what I'm doing.

Comment: Sorry I don't know the  shortcut to encasing code.

Comment: Error being returned is: Requested value '0x0000000000000000000012107A8D' was not found

Comment: I gave a +1 to the next thing you should try. See below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IDs = (TagLabels)Convert.ToInt64(someID, 16);
```

EDIT: You have a string that is in hex format and not a direct number. So, it needs conversion to int first.

If the Enum value exists, you can cast an int value to Enum type.

EDIT2: Changed after Marc's suggestion from `Convert.ToInt32` to `Convert.ToInt64`

Comment: You may want ToInt64, considering the enum is of type Int64 (long)

Answer (score 4):

Enum.Parse is intended to convert a string representation of the symbolic name into an enum val, as in `Enum.Parse("TurnLeft")`. If what you have is a string giving the numeric value, then you should just parse the string as the corresponding integer type and cast it to the Enum val.

```
IDs = (TagLabels)long.Parse("0x0000000000000000000012107A8D");
```

Answer (score 1):

SomeID is a string and your enum is a long.

Try using TurnLeft instead of "0x0000000000000000000012107A8D"

Answer (score 0):

Where is the string you're parsing? Aren't you trying to turn a string like "TurnLeft" into TagLabels.TurnLeft?

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx)

Comment: I'm trying to use the tag string to set the ID variable